# Is it possible to display auto suggestions above the text field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I'm trying to display option of suggestions above the textfield in flutter.

Can anyone please guide me how it can be done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KgKU.png)

Using Autocomplete widget

Comment: Who do you mean by above textfield? Any screen available?

Comment: Hey Hi, Please be more specific about your question.

Comment: post code in ur question